# How to restrict files to certain users in Amazon-S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Im am trying to experiment with Amazon-S3

Lets say, for example, I am trying to create an app where users can back up pictures they take from their phone.
Now I want to use Amazon-s3 as the data storage solution.

I will need to restrict access so that users can download only their files that they uploaded and not somebody else

For this scenario, would I have to use IAM account for each users? And use that to implement access policies? I'm not really sure if this is the best way for it to be done

Answer (score 0):

IAM Users should not be used for application authentication, Amazon Cognito is a better option for that. This post shows how to use policy variables to restrict users to specific prefixes in a S3 Bucket: http://mobile.awsblog.com/post/Tx1OSMBRHZVM9V0/Understanding-Amazon-Cognito-Authentication-Part-3-Roles-and-Policies